# Knockout & Typescript

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

What I want to achieve: A menu bar that will display different div data.

What I have:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="foreach: menuItems">
            <button data-bind="text: name, click: navigate" class="buttonTD"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
```

viewModel:

```
this._tabs = ko.observableArray([
            { id: '1', name: "Compliance", navigate: 'tab2Visible: ko.observable(false)', style: 'active' },
            { id: '2', name: "ITC ", navigate: 'tab3Visible: ko.observable(false)', style: 'inactive' },
            { id: '3', name: "Check", navigate: 'tab4Visible: ko.observable(false)', style: 'inactive' },
            { id: '4', name: "Check Champion", navigate: 'tab5Visible: ko.observable(false)', style: 'inactive' },
            { id: '5', name: "Tech", navigate: 'tab6Visible: ko.observable(false)', style: 'inactive' },
            { id: '6', name: "Comm", navigate: 'tab7Visible: ko.observable(false)', style: 'inactive' },
            { id: '7', name: "Order", navigate: 'tab8Visible: ko.observable(false)', style: 'inactive' },
            { id: '8', name: "Order Rejected", navigate: 'tab9Visible: ko.observable(false)', style: 'inactive' },
            { id: '9', name: "Cancel", navigate: 'tab10Visible: ko.observable(false)', style: 'inactive' }
        ]);
this.menuItems = this._tabs;
```

How can be that array changes that when I click on button 1 to show me the div 1, when I click on button2 to show me the div3 and so on.

Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Really, @SamHolder? He obviously 1) Is new to SO and 2) Does not speak English that well. There are better ways of helping him out, to better encourage his further use of SO, than using snarky comments.

Comment: What doesn't work at the moment? What does it actually do and how does that differ from what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you! IronMan84, you are right. Is my first project with  knockout, require and typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to have a single variable that holds the current tab based on the id. Updating and keeping track of multiple bool variables makes the code harder to maintain. Additionally, you need to make a click event that isn't a string.

You probably want something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="foreach: menuItems">
            <button data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.onTabClick" class="buttonTD"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div data-bind="visible: visibleTab() == 1">Tab 1</div>
<div data-bind="visible: visibleTab() == 2">Tab 2</div>
<!-- etc... -->
<div data-bind="visible: visibleTab() == 9">Tab 9</div>
```

Then in the ViewModel:

```
this.visibleTab = ko.observable(1);
this.menuItems = ko.observableArray([
        { id: '1', name: "Compliance", style: 'active' },
        { id: '2', name: "ITC ", style: 'inactive' },
        { id: '3', name: "Check", style: 'inactive' },
        { id: '4', name: "Check Champion", style: 'inactive' },
        { id: '5', name: "Tech", style: 'inactive' },
        { id: '6', name: "Comm", style: 'inactive' },
        { id: '7', name: "Order", style: 'inactive' },
        { id: '8', name: "Order Rejected", style: 'inactive' },
        { id: '9', name: "Cancel", style: 'inactive' }
    ]);

this.onTabClick = (item) => {
    this.visibleTab(item.id);
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xahaayhm/1/)

Comment: David Sherret, Thank you very much, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Daniel.Cristian great. You should be able to take this example and work it to fit your exact situation.

Comment: this is what i've done and it's great, works nice and smood. Thanks again. I've looked and tried here only complicated ways and you provided the winning line: 'this.onTabClick = (item) => {
    this.visibleTab(item.id);
}' and the proper html binding. I'm a newbie, but I already like this...!